# Eclipse showing false-positive missing include in xsl problems after upgrading to 2021-12

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, xslt

In our legacy maven project are several hundred XSL problems after I upgraded our team-wide used Eclipse Neon to Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22). Due to the upgrade, I also had to upgrade some modules such as TestNG (6.8.21 -> 7.3.0) and the maven-war-plugin (2.2 -> 3.3.2).

The project builds without problems via Maven or our Jenkins server and also runs on all our applications environments (on JBoss servers).

However, if I start to setup our new Eclipse, the IDE shows these problems as shown (corporate file names censored).

[image: screenshot]

I can provide more information on detailed matters on demand.

**Q: Did anybody had a similar issue or knows how to correct this?**

I appreciate every help given!

EDIT: I don't do anything fancy with the IDE. I simply download and unzip the Eclipse version, import my maven project and after validation, the errors just show up. And the same behaviour occurs with Eclipse 2021-03.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example with which your issue can be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the current Eclipse 2022-03, not in the outdated Eclipse 2021-12 you upgraded to.

Comment: @howlger I can't really provide this. All I did was unzip the new Eclipse version, import my maven project and after validation, the errors occur.

Comment: What prevents you from providing a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Are the messages wrong?

Comment: @nitind Yes, as I said: It is a legacy project so it all works perfectly fine. Just now upon using the new version these errors show up.

Comment: @howlger I wrote down the steps I've done in the EDIT. Apart from that I don't really know what else to tell you. The imported project is confidential.

Comment: That's not really what I asked, as I have no doubt about it running fine. Are the XML messages new as well? What do they say?

Comment: Please show as little code as possible, enough to reproduce your issue and tell us the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Could you share the xslt code?